# Need circuit to toggle voltage between two paths

Tags: circuit-design, schematics

I need to create a circuit to allow me to toggle a source voltage from one path to another. I need to be able to toggle the path from the first path to the second while a second voltage is active, and go back to the first path when the second voltage is not active, such as in this diagram.

[image: block diagram]

P.s. Please do not suggest using a switch, I can only toggle by using a second incoming voltage

Comment: Use analog switches. They are electronic devices (not mechanical switches) and can be controlled by voltage

Comment: Multiplexer.... Electronics stores still exist?

Comment: Use a relay, this will do exactly what you explain.

Comment: "*Diagrams are appreciated but not necessary ...*". Generally, for electrical circuits, diagrams or schematics *are* necessary. It's how we communicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0fFLV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Relay voltage source switch.*

- When V2 is not preset V1 will power LOAD1.
- When V2 is high enough to energise the relay the V1 will power LOAD2.

[image]

*Figure 2. A typical relay.*

- Choose the relay coil voltage to match V2.
- Choose relay contact voltage and current ratings to meet or exceed the supply voltage and load current.
- If using DC check that they are adequately rated for DC.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an analog multiplexer. Depending on the input combinaison, a path will be maid from a point to another. If you use a digital multiplexer, the output will be equal to the multiplexer power supply. If you want to have different voltage level on the output you have to use an analog mux.

[image]

This solution may not work if the mux drive too much current (see [that datasheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT4051.pdf) for exemple).

To drive larger current, you may need to use relay. It's like a switch but trigger by current instead of your finger. You will need to make a little circuit to determine which relay to trigger but it wont be that hard.

Both component are findable in electronic store a pretty low price. (exept the relay if you want a very large one..)